# Launching Java application on CENTOS yields "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, centos, swt

I have 64-bit installation of CENTOS v6.5 final.

I have a 32-bit compiled Java application, which I created with WindowBuilder/SWT Designer/SWT/Composite inside Eclipse.

The application runs perfectly on Windows 7, where I created the Java application, from a Windows 7 command prompt:

```
java -cp "bin/*;lib/*" PkgNetAccelerator32.netAcceleratorApp
```

Inside the lib folder is swt.jar, and the Manifest.jar file that I automatically created. Yes, I downloaded the Linux version of swt.jar for use on CENTOS and placed that file in the /lib folder. I copied over the /bin and /lib and placed both folders at "/home/jmr/Documents/NetAccelerator/Java".

The problem that I receive the following error, when I try and start the Java application from a terminal window on my CENTOS box. The prompt is:

```
[jmr@sarah-linux Java]$ java -cp "bin/*;lib/*" PkgNetAccelerator32.netAcceleratorApp
Error: Could not find or load main class PkgNetAccelerator32.netAcceleratorApp
```

I do not have CLASSPATH or JAVA_HOME defined in my global environment variables list, although I do have the -cp option set. As stated above, swt.jar on the CENTOS box is the Linux version.

Here is the version information from Java:

```
[jmr@sarah-linux Java]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.4.el6_5-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

The folder layout is fine.

```
[jmr@sarah-linux Java]$ ls -l bin
total 8
drwx------. 3 jmr jmr 4096 Dec 30 12:43 org
drwx------. 2 jmr jmr 4096 Dec 30 12:56 PkgNetAccelerator32
[jmr@sarah-linux Java]$ ls -l lib
total 1828
drwx------. 2 jmr jmr    4096 Dec 31 13:18 Linux
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 jmr jmr    7994 Dec 30 14:08 Manifest.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 jmr jmr  124252 Dec 26 13:06 resty-0.3.2.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 jmr jmr 1727233 Dec 31 13:18 swt.jar
drwx------. 2 jmr jmr    4096 Dec 31 13:18 Windows
[jmr@sarah-linux Java]$ ls bin/PkgNetAccelerator32/
netAcceleratorApp$1.class  netAcceleratorApp.class
```

I am at a loss for how to fix the problem.

For whatever it is worth, I tried the following, but that gave the following error:

```
[jmr@sarah-linux Java]$ java -cp "bin/[An/*;lib/*" -jar lib/Manifest.jar PkgNetAccelerator32.netAcceleratorApp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Linux/Unix systems a classpath separator for Java programs [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#OS_specific_notes) `:` (colon) instead of `;` (semicolon). Change your Java call to:

`java -cp "bin/*:lib/*" PkgNetAccelerator32.netAcceleratorApp`

Comment: I still have an issue of "Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM", but that is another issue/topic. I had to manually download the 64-bit libraries using "More..." and now I can see my app on CENTOS. Yay!