# JDK 1.7 Error: Could not find or load main class when using command "java -cp" with multiple jars

Tags: java, maven, classpath, java-7

i have created a maven project named a-test and only a main class in it

```
package com.jar.test.a;
public class AppTest 
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    System.out.println( "hi test");
  }
}
```

package it

```
 mvn clean install
 cd target
```

and it works as running

```
 java -cp a-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.jar.test.a.AppTest
```

or

```
 java -cp *.jar com.jar.test.a.AppTest
```

and it prints

```
 hi test
```

but it will issue error when i want to specify a multiple jars path (i want to import another java project)

```
java -cp *.jar:/usr/lib/*.jar com.jar.test.a.AppTest
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class

it will appear the same error when i have test this on macbook os x 10.10.3 and centos6

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892135/launching-java-application-on-centos-yields-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) but it did not work for me.

Comment: Hope you executed above command after doing "cd target"

Answer (score 2):

You should issue:

```
java -cp *:/usr/lib/* com.jar.test.a.AppTest
```

... since `*` implies `*.jar`.  See [Understanding class path wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) :

> Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *, which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the class path entry foo/* specifies all JAR files in the directory named foo. A classpath entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory. Files will be considered regardless of whether or not they are hidden (that is, have names beginning with '.').

Be careful with a bare single `*` though, since your shell will probably want to expand it as a wildcard, in which case you can quote it.

Answer (score 0):

You should excecute it like this (Unix systems):

```
java -cp a-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:lib/*:. com.jar.test.a.AppTest
```